# How to insert data from file into postgres table using Luigi?

Tags: python-2.7, luigi

I am getting error "Exception: Cannot map None to Task/dict/list". I am new to Luigi. please advisehow can insert into postgres table by reading data from file.

Answer (score 1):

That's beacuse `requires` method must return a Taks instance or a list/dict of tasks:

```
def requires(self):
    return CsvDataReadFromFile()
```